# java xpath remove element from xml

Tags: java, xml, xpath, removechild

I am trying to remove an element and child elements from an xml file.  Specifically appender with the name Testlogging.

First this is how my xml file looks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="null" threshold="null">

<appender class="DailyLogFileAppender" name="Testlogging">
    <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100MB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="2"/>
    <param name="rootDir" value="c:\Logs"/>
    <param name="componentId" value="Testlogging"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyyMMdd"/>
    <layout class="SyslogPatternLayout">
        <param ConversionPattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} [%-5p] {%t} %c [%D] - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Here is my java code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbfact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = dbfact.newDocumentBuilder();
Document d = builder.parse(xmlFile);
        XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList nl = (NodeList)xp.compile("//appender").evaluate(d,XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for(int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)
        {
            if(xp.compile("./@name").evaluate(nl.item(i)).equals("Testlogging"))
            {
                Node node = nl.item(i);
                node.removeChild(nl.item(i));
            }
        }
```

I would like to remove everything for this appender but an exception is being thrown.    It's probably something simple I am missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the exception ?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist.

Comment: There seems to be the solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719384/why-can-i-not-remove-a-child-element-ive-just-found-not-found-err. You seem to be trying to remove an element by treating it as its own child?

Comment: Sorry I am still confused on how the code fix would work.  How should my code look?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you need to call `removeChild` on the parent node of the node you want to remove and you need to process the `NodeList` in reverse order (as W3C DOM collections are "live" collections that can change with any DOM manipulation (https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#td-live)) so use an approach like

```
    NodeList nl = (NodeList)xp.compile("//appender[@name = 'Testlogging']").evaluate(d,XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = nl.getLength() - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
       nl.item(i).getParentNode().removeChild(nl.item(i));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.   Odd that we need to process it in reverse but It does make sense after thinking about it.  Thanks :)

Comment: It would be cool if you add why we have to iterate the list in reverse order to your answer. But anyways, it works. Thanks

Comment: @GabrielBB, I have added a note and link to the reason, namely "live" DOM collections.